# Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object

Tags: php, html

I'm working with a pagination and I get this error is the first time I work with this, I a appreciate the help thank you!

Fatal error: Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\pritcluster\register_companies.php on line 47

```
 include_once 'config/database.php';

try {

    // Find out how many items are in the table
    $total = $con -> query('SELECT company_name, email, tel, website 
             FROM company') -> fetch_assoc();

    // How many items to list per page
        $limit = 10;
    // How many pages will there be
         $pages = mysqli_fetch_array($total, $limit);
    // What page are we currently on?
         $page = min($pages, filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array (
             'option' => array(
                 'default' => 1,
                 'min_range' => 1,
             ),
         )));
    // Calculate the offset for the query
         $offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;
    // Some information to display to the user
         $start = $offset + 1;
         $end = min(($offset + $limit), $total);
    // The "back" link
         $prevlink = ($page > 1) ? '<a herf="?page=1" title = "First page"> &laquo;</a>
   <a href="?page=' . ($page - 1) . '" title="Previous page">&lsaquo;</a>' : '<span
          class="disabled">&laquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&lsaquo;</span>';
    // The "forward" link
$nextlink = ($page < $pages) ? '<a href="?page=' . ($page + 1) . '" title="Next
  page">&rsaquo;</a> <a href="?page=' . $pages . '" title="Last page">&raquo;</a>' : 
 '<span class="disabled">&rsaquo;</span> <span class="disabled">&raquo;</span>';  
           // Prepare the paged query
      $stmt = $con->prepare('
        SELECT
        company_name, email, tel, website
    FROM
        company
    ORDER BY
        ASC
    LIMIT
        :limit
    OFFSET
        :offset
        ');

   // Bind the query params
$stmt->bindParam(':limit', $limit, PDO:: PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO:: PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: error means `$stmt` isnt an object, check to see that `prepare()` didnt fail

Comment: If you are using mysql, then afaik, you need to use LIMIT `[count],[offset];`

Comment: @jeroenvisser101 I don't understand your answer, what do you mean?

Comment: @PatrickEvans yeah the query was wrong I fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think query is wrong.

```
 SELECT
        company_name, email, tel, website
    FROM
        company
    ORDER BY
        ASC
    LIMIT
        :limit
    OFFSET
        :offset
```

You are not using any column in order by. Please run this query in phpmyadmin(or in console) and check.

Comment: Yes is inst correct I fix it.